# Solving $7^x\bmod {29} = 23 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have $$7^x\bmod {29} = 23 $$
It is possible to get $x$ by trying out different numbers but that will not be possible if $x$ is actually big.

Are there any other solutions for this equation?

Kind regards

Comment: In general, there might not be a solution for $x$ to the equivalence $a^x\equiv b\mod{n}$, for instance $3^x\equiv 5\pmod{8}$ has no integer solutions (*as $3^2\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ it follows that $3^x$ is always equivalent to either $0$ or $3$ modulo $8$ and never equivalent to $5$*).  When there are solutions and $n$ is prime (*as is the case here for $n=29$*) you will have infinitely many solutions noting that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ for $a$ coprime to $p$ by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: In your specific case, it so happens that $23$ is in the cycle generated by $7$ and you have that $7^x\equiv 23\pmod{29}$ for all positive $x\equiv 4\pmod{7}$

Comment: Yeah, the general problem is called the discrete logarithm, and it is a hard problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm

Comment: As luck would have it.  $23 \equiv -6$ and $23^2 \equiv 36 \equiv 7$.  So we have $7^{2x} \equiv 7$.  We know $7^{28} \equiv 1$ so we must have $2x-1$ must be a multiple an odd divisor of $28$.  But $7$ is the only non-trivial odd divisor of $28$ so unless $7^7\equiv 1 \pmod{28}$ there will not be any solutions.  And if $7^7\equiv 1$ then if this has a solition it will have a solution less than $7$.  So we must have $2x-1 =7$ or $x =4$.  If any solution exist it must be that.... But I don't see any way to *generalize* that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trial and error is your only option for this type of problem.

The general problem is called the [discrete logarithm,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) and it is hard.

Give prime $p$ and $a,b$ not divisible by $p,$ finding an integer $x$ so that:

$$a^x\equiv b\pmod p$$

might not even have a solution. There is a solution if and only if $o(b)\mid o(a),$ where $o(c)$ is the multiplicative order of $c,$ the smallest $k>0$ such that $c^k\equiv 1\pmod p.$

But even computing $o(a)$ is non-trivial, unless you can quickly list the divisors of $p-1.$

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything but trial and error.

But look.  $7^2 \equiv 23 \equiv -6 \pmod {29}$

$7^{2x} \equiv 36 \equiv 7\pmod {29}$.

So $7^{2x-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {29}$.

We know by FLT the $7^{28}\equiv 1$ so for the least power to which $7$ is a multiple of $1$ must be a divisor of $28$.

So $2x-1$ is a multiple of a divisor of $28$.  Immediately we have $2x-1$ is odd so it must be a multiple of an odd divisor of $28$.

The only nontrivial odd divisor of $28$ is $7$.  So test to see if $7^7\equiv 1 \pmod {29}$.  We have $7^7 \equiv 1\pmod {29}$. That was lucky. so we have $2x-1 = 7k$ and  as there are only $7$ values of $7^w\pmod {29}$, we might as well assume $x \le 6$. so $x = 4$ is only option.  Let's try that.

$7^4 \equiv 23\pmod {29}$.

Yep.... that worked.

Answer (score 1):

your question $7^x\pmod {29} = 23$ can be written as $7^x$ - $29$ $\lfloor \frac {7^x}{29} \rfloor$ = $23$. Maybe you can proceed with this or maybe the most efficient way to solve will be to use trial and error.